Newest Questions tab showing last active user rather than the asker
Apparently this is stackexchange wide  and is a bug.  Here is the illustration from the question
"Newest Questions" tab showing last active user instead of the asker
I did ask, it is believed that "Newest"  still shows questions in strict  order of asking, it just suppresses the time and username of the asker if there has been more recent modification by others

